# LINQ select distinct, multiple columns

Tags: mysql, linq, .net-4.0, distinct, sql-server-express

I've seen several other posts like this but can't quite work it out for my situation. If I have a forum with a number of posts, I want to get a list of the latest posts - but only one post per thread. So I want Distinct(threadID) but max(Time). Those on their own are easy enough, but I want to also select the other columns related to that particular row

```
        var posts = from s in websiteDB.Forum_Post
                    orderby s.Time
                    select new ForumPostSummary()
                    {
                        UserID = s.UserID ?? default(int),
                        Time = s.Time ?? default(int),
                        Subject = s.Subject,
                        ThreadID = s.ThreadID ?? default(int)
                    };
        posts = posts.Take(10);
```

Example table:

```
| UserID | Time  | Subject | ThreadID |
| 1      | 10:00 | ABC     | 999      |
| 2      | 10:01 | Re:DEF  | 998      |
| 3      | 10:02 | Re:ABC  | 999      |
| 4      | 09:40 | DEF     | 998      |
| 5      | 09:45 | Re:DEF  | 998      |
```

I would want the rows by userID 3 (latest time for thread 999, and latest time overall) and userID 2 (latest time for thread 998). I'm referencing the UserID for results simply for the purposes of explaining which rows I want. I'm actually querying data from an MySQL database and inserting into a SqlExpress one, though this problem applies to both databases in slightly different forms!

```
| 3      | 10:02 | Re:ABC  | 999      |
| 2      | 10:01 | Re:DEF  | 998      |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to *group* by ThreadID, then order each group by time (descending) and take the first value from each group. So something like:

```
var posts = from s in websiteDB.Forum_Post
            group s by s.ThreadID into thread
            select thread.OrderByDescending(t => t.Time).First() into recent
            select new ForumPostSummary
            {
                UserID = recent.UserID ?? default(int),
                Time = recent.Time ?? default(int),
                Subject = recent.Subject,
                ThreadID = recent.ThreadID ?? default(int)
            };
posts = posts.Take(10);
```

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I guess I was confusing myself with multiple selects and the grouping, all within the same query! I also have a join in there (not in original question) but I've managed to re-insert that ok. Thanks again.